# inserting from select and static elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

im trying to insert an id depending on another table, but i dont know how to do so, i have to do it this way since i am inserting multiples values at the time.

this is my failed attempt at doing so

```
 INSERT INTO producto (NumeroEconomico, Order_Id,Marca,Modelo,ano,placas,Product_Id,Inventario_Id) 
values ('ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1',SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293'),
('ad-102', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2015','aer5647','1',SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161019329')
```

thx

Comment: @Minh i get syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your subqueries in parentheses.

```
INSERT INTO producto VALUES 
    ('ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1',(SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293')),
    ('ad-102', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2015','aer5647','1',(SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161019329'))
```

Comment: @pato.llaguno If this solved your problem please confirm this as your answer.

Comment: as follow up , is there a way so the insert will only happen if the select actually returns a row without having to do the seperate query?

Comment: Not with the way your doing it now. To do that I would create a temp table and populate it using whatever logic you need. Then do an insert with the values from the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an INSERT INTO SELECT?

```
INSERT INTO producto
(NumeroEconomico, Order_Id,Marca,Modelo,ano,placas,Product_Id,Inventario_Id)
SELECT 'ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1',Id 
FROM Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293'
```

Comment: @pato.llaguno This style of statement would only insert if `serie` returned a result as you asked. However, would not allow multiple rows to be inserted at the same time like the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO producto (NumeroEconomico, Order_Id,Marca,Modelo,ano,placas,Product_Id,Inventario_Id) 
SELECT 'ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1', Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293'
```

Check the right SQL syntax at:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp